# Python quiz code, not printing correct and incorrect when answered

Tags: python, iteration

can someone help me with this code as it is not producing 'correct' or 'incorrect' when the questions are answered. What im thinking someone will do is when each answer is produced and answered if they got it correct it will say correct but if they have gotten it wrong it will say incorrect. At the moment it just says incorrect when you finish all ten questions.

```
num1=0
num2=0
numofq=0

while numofq <10:
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    correctAns = num1 * num2
    question = str(num1) + "x" + str(num2)
    ans = input(question)
    numofq=numofq+1
if ans == correctAns:
   print ("Correct")
else:
   print ("Incorrect")
```

Comment: Just add an extra indent to your `if... else` section, so it goes inside the scope of the `while` block.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Shift the if/else block inside the `while`. And while at it, move `import random` to the top of the file, no need to import it every iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Your `if`-`else` blocks are not indented right, they should be part of the `while` loop:

```
num1=0
num2=0
numofq=0

while numofq <10:
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    correctAns = num1 * num2
    question = str(num1) + "x" + str(num2)
    ans = input(question)
    numofq=numofq+1
    if ans == correctAns:
       print ("Correct")
    else:
       print ("Incorrect")
```

But while we are at it, you can improvise your code by

1. using better variable names
2. `.format` for string formatting
3. putting the `import` at the top
4. proper indentation with line breaks

so that the program now looks like

```
import random

num1 = num2 = 0
questions_asked = 0

while questions_asked <10:
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    answer = num1 * num2
    question = "{} x {}: ".format(num1, num2)
    user_answer = int(input(question))
    print("Correct" if user_answer == answer else "Incorrect")
    questions_asked += 1
```

This outputs:

```
6 x 4: 24
Correct
2 x 7: 14
Correct
3 x 4: 12
Correct
...
```

Comment: mu your code still does not work, it still prints incorrect each time

Comment: @Bobdylan Are you on python3 or 2? if python 2, this will work, if python 3, replace `user_answer = input(question)` with `user_answer = int(input(question))`.

Comment: @Bobdylan if that helped, dont forget to accept the answer by selecting the tick mark to the left of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
numofq = 0
correct = 0
wrong = 0
while numofq < 10:
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    correctAns = num1 * num2
    question = str(num1) + "x" + str(num2)
    ans = input(question)
    if correctAns == ans:
        print 'Correct'
        correct += 1
    else:
        wrong += 1
        print 'Incorrect'
    numofq = numofq + 1
print 'Correct :', correct, 'Incorrect :', wrong
```